# A blue question mark shows up when trying to import a photo (HTML)

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse

I'm thinking that it's my file path that may be wrong?

Inside my src folder, I have the jpg photo I want to use (brush.jpg).

This is what I have for my code.

```
site.println("<p><img src = brush.jpg alt= 'brush' width= '500' height= '400'></img></p>");
```

For some reason when it runs, it's showing the outline where the photo should be (including the blue boxed question mark) but with no photo.

Please help.

Comment: What URL will generate that HTML, and what is your directory structure where the image is stored?

Comment: the structure goes like this:  Project Name -> Src File -> brush.jpg

Comment: And where is your html file? in `Src` folder?

Comment: the HTML file is in my data folder which is under my Project Name. (same scope as my src file.) In my Project Name folder, it consists of Src, Test, Data, Doc, Lib. Then My HTML file is in my Data folder. My source code is in my src and so is my jpg.